# How to continue the autofill in this format?

Tags: filesystems, auto-form-fill

So right now I have this in range A1:A9

A1: 1.1.1

A2: 1.1.2

A3: Empty cell

A4: 1.2.1

A:5 1.2.2

A6: Empty cell

A7: 1.3.1

A8: 1.3.2

A9: Empty cell

What I need to do is be able to drag this down (autofill) so that the number formatting continues in this way:

A10: 1.4.1

A11: 1.4.2

A12: Empty cell

A13: 1.5.1

A14: 1.5.2

A15: Empty cell

etc.....

Is there someone out there who can solve this?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?